# Create scatter plot where the color is based on year without adding extra column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this data in a csv table

| TIME | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-07-03T00:00:00Z | 0.08 | 0.30 |
| 2021-07-03T00:00:00Z | 0.20 | 0.12 |

And i want to create a scatter plot between variable X and Y, and color the dots based on the year of that data as seen in time. I know i could add an extra column with the year in it, but is there a more elegant way of doing this without adding columns?

Comment: You can get *year* using datetime. Convert this column to datetime and then use: `df['time'].dt.year` as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 'cheap' way to color your scatter dots according to the year is to directly use matplotlib's [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) plot and pass the year as argument for the [`c` parameter of scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
mydf = pd.DataFrame((
               (datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 23, 00), 0.08, 0.3),
               (datetime.datetime(2021, 2,2,1,2,55), 0.2, 0.12), 
               (datetime.datetime(2022, 2,3,11, 00), 0.12, 0.7)
           ),
           columns=("TIME", 'X', 'Y')
       )

plt.scatter(mydf.X, mydf.Y, c=mydf.TIME.dt.year)

plt.show()
```

[image]
Then you can use the `cmap` parameter to specify what colormap you want to apply.

Comment: +1: Ah, great; matplotlib's scatter function again beats pandas'. There, the first option "A scalar or sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap and norm." is conveniently omitted. Much more elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without creating an additional column, but it won't be more elegant. [`DataFrame.plot.scatter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html?highlight=scatter#pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter) supports different values for its color argument:

> **c**: str, int or array-like, optional
>
> The color of each point. Possible values are:
>
> - A single color string referred to by name, RGB or RGBA code, for instance ‘red’ or ‘#a98d19’.
> - A sequence of color strings referred to by name, RGB or RGBA code, which will be used for each point’s color recursively. For
>   instance [‘green’,’yellow’] all points will be filled in green or
>   yellow, alternatively.
> - A column name or position whose values will be used to color the marker points according to a colormap.

So instead of doing:

```
df['Year'] = df['TIME'].dt.year
df.plot.scatter('X', 'Y', c='Year')
```

You could then manually derive colors using a matplotlib's color map objects:

```
def scale_to_unity(s):
    return (s - s.min()) / (s.max() - s.min())

def series_to_colors(s, cmap='viridis'):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    color_map = plt.get_cmap(cmap)
    return scale_to_unity(s).apply(color_map)

df.plot.scatter('X', 'Y', c=series_to_colors(df.TIME))
```

Like before, you can discard the precise time information by only using `df.TIME.dt.year` in the last line. However, the first variant looks much less cumbersome to me.

Comment: I think your solution is just as valid(+1)! Maybe a bit longer, but you have already added the functionality of specifying the cmap you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = pd.to_datetime(df.TIME).dt.year
c = c.tolist()
X = df.X
Y = df.Y
plt.scatter(X,Y,c=c)
```

[image]

Don't have to create a column.  Just convert the year to a list and then you can map whatever colour based on the list.